# Creating a File-Based Cron Job in Linux

Tags: php, linux, csv, cron

I am trying to do what I think is a pretty complicated task.

I would like to execute a PHP script, but only if a file named import_products.csv exists in /var/import.  The reason why is because that script attempts to import the aforementioned CSV file, and therefore I don't want it to error if it attempts to run the script every minute.

On the other hand, I DO want the script to run every minute (or even 2 or 4 times per minute) if there IS a file.  So what I am invisioning is something like this.

I'd create the cron job to run every minute, which does the following:

- Check if /var/import/import_products.csv exists

If it does not exist, exit the script now.

- Execute product_import.php (this would be stored in the same folder as my cronjob file)
- After execution completes, delete /var/import/import_products.csv

I will be using a separate daemon to generate these CSV files, all that is imperative here is that it only runs the PHP script if the file exists.

If there is a way to do this without using cron, that would work too. Basically I just want it to run that PHP script every time a new import_products.csv is written and delete the file afterwards.  Cron jobs are the only way I know for sure to do this.

Comment: you probable want to look in to `inotify` a better approach than cron\php

Comment: Make life easy: run the import script every minute and check for the existence of the file in the PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I could envision you doing this. The first is, if possible, the easiest, which would be to [add in checks to the PHP script itself](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to see whether or not the file is present. If your product imports will take longer than one minute you'll also have to consider what happens if the file is *still there* while another import is happening already.

The second way would be to create a bash or shell script of some kind that will [check for the existence of the file](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) and then run the command to execute the PHP script if so, then add the shell script to your cron instead of the PHP script itself.

Comment: Can the PHP script delete the file after running the rest of it, however?  I'm not too familiar with PHP - in fact, the script I'm using was written by the person who made the product import extension.

Comment: Actually, I answered my own question.  As much as you'd think delete(filename) works, it's unlink(filename).

Answer (score 0):

You can include the file checking within the php script through Exception handling, with a little php side overhead.